# GitHub action trigger at pull request approval

Tags: github, github-actions

I am working on a project in which GitHub action will trigger when the pull request is approved as mentioned [here](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.2/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-a-workflow-when-a-pull-request-is-approved). But in my case, there are at least 2 approvals required to approve the pull request, so at each approval, actions start to run. Is there any way to run the GitHub actions on just one approval and ignore the others?

```
on:
  pull_request_review:
    types: [submitted]

jobs:
  approved:
    if: github.event.review.state == 'approved'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "This PR was approved"
```

Comment: Either it's in the payload (try dumping `github.event`) or you're going to have to use the [API to fetch all reviews](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/reviews)

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70438914/trigger-a-github-action-on-pull-request-approval-and-path